# issue in querying mySQL db hosted in Cloud SQL with Google Run service

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

For a project I had to create an online db instance using MySQL in a Google Cloud SQL instance, then create a rest API to connect with the database instance in order to querying it.
Following the Google's tutorial (Link below) , I created the REST-API as service in Google Cloud Shell Editor using node.js. Via the Cloud Shell I was able to build and deploy the service, and I created a cloud Run instance connected to it.
If i connect to the basic get (see code below) it works fine, if i try to get information from the database i get nothing in return.
The url message id is 200, the query seems to be viewed as done or at least it doesn't generate an error, and after i just get nothing (if you see the code below we should get the information returned by the query in the results variable, but it is empty).
Can you help me understanding what is missing?

Here the scripts i mentioned above:

index.js

```html
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();

//pool variable
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    user:'username',
    password:'password',
    database:'dbname',
    socketpath:'the instance name given by the instance info page',
});

app.use(express.json());
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('oraigo rest api listening on port ${port}');
});

// function get to test on port 8080
app.get("/", async (req, res)=>{
    res.json({status:"mario!!"});
});

//app get function to get from db info
app.get("/:user", async (req, res)=>{
    const query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE id_user=?";
    pool.query(query, [req.params.user], (error, results)=>{
        res.json(results);
        /*if(!results[0]){
            res.json({status:"not fuond"});
        }
        else{
            res.json({status:"ppp"});
        }*/
        //res.json({status:"siamo giusti"});
    });

});
```

package.json

```html
{
    "name": "namename",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "info desc",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "Gigi",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1"
    }
}
```

To do so I've watched many videos from Google Cloud Tech Youtube channel, in particular this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_w_idf928WY
I've followed everything, except that i'm using the Cloud Shell instead of coding locally (but should be excatly the same)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by forcing the connection to the SQL DataBase in the connection settings, during the service creation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that your `socketpath` variable is not being named and set correctly.

It should be named `socketPath` and not `socketpath`, with the value being set to `'/cloudsql/<PROJECT-ID>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>'`

**Note:** `<PROJECT-ID>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>` is also referred to sometimes as `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` within samples and tutorials.

So in context, your pool creation should look like this:

```js
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  user: <YOUR_DB_USER>,
  password: <YOUR_DB_PASS>,
  database: <YOUR_DB_NAME>,
  socketPath: '/cloudsql/<PROJECT-ID>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>',
});
```

So if your Cloud SQL Instance was named **mysql-instance**, in the region **us-central1**, within a project with the name and ID of **my-cool-project** then your socket path parameter would be the following:
`socketPath: '/cloudsql/my-cool-project:us-central1:mysql-instance'`

P.S. Here is the [tutorial source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/serverless-expeditions/tree/main/cloud-sql-rest-api) for the video link you shared if you want to reference it directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the name of the instance is corret. 
I managed to make it works by forcing the connection to the sql db in the connection settings, during the service creation

Comment: do you mind elaborating on your solution? I am curious what you mean by "forcing the connection".

Comment: I think I explained myself badly in the previous message. I mean that automatically with the creation of the container image all the information for the connection to the database is also set. I thought the rest was all automatic. Instead, during the creation of the service in the connection settings, the Cloud SQL connection must still be set to the database you intend to use. I had seen a video where this last step was omitted and it all worked the same, not in my case.